# Marketing Cloud - Import - User does not have access to Salesforce objects or reports

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, dataextensions, data-import

I am new to SF and SFMC.

I am trying to create a new import activity in Email Builder.

Everytime I try to create a new Data Extension using a Report through SF, I receive this error.

**Import Definition Validation Error:
  User does not have access to Salesforce objects or reports.**

Are there permissions on SF or SFMC that I need to enable in order to create this Data Extension with a Report.

I am conducting the Report on a Custom Object, Subscription, with two Master-detail lookup's to Contact and another custom object, Event.

Comment: Have you "integrated" the user in Admin -> My Users to associate the SFMC user with a CRM user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Marketing Cloud User will need to be configured as an integrated user, which links their Sales Cloud account to the Marketing Cloud Account. Refer to procedural steps [on this page](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/manage_users/) to enable users in Marketing Cloud.

You should see an 'Integrate' link on the user profile in Marketing Cloud:

[image: integrate user]